# Write to S3 using PutObjectRequest while still generating stream

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, streamwriter

I am converting an application that currently uses the Windows file system to read and store files.

While reading each line of an input file, it modifies the data, and then writes it out to an output file:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\out.txt", false))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\temp\in.txt", Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //Create modifiedLine from line data
            ...
            writer.WriteLine(modifiedLine);
        }
    }
}
```

So far, I have been able to write to S3 using a PutObjectRequest, but only with the entire file contents at once:

```
//Set up stream
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
writer.Write(theEntireModifiedFileContents);
writer.Flush();
stream.Position = 0;

var putRequest = new PutObjectRequest()
{
    BucketName = destinationBucket,
    Key = destinationKey,
    InputStream = stream
};

var response = await s3Client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest);
```

Given that these are going to be large files, I would prefer to keep the line-by-line approach rather than having to send the entire file contents at once.

Is there any way to maintain a similar behavior to the file system example above with S3?

Answer (score 0):

S3 is an object store and does not support modifications in-place, appending, etc.

However, it is possible to meet your goals if certain criteria is met / understood:

1) Realize that it will take more code to do this than simply modifying your code to buffer the line output and then upload as a single object.

2) You can upload each line as part of the REST API PUT stream. This means that you will need to continuously upload data until complete. Basically you are doing a slow upload of a single S3 object while you process each line.

3) You can use the multi-part API to upload each line as a single part of a multi-part transfer. Then combine parts once complete. Note: I don't remember if each part has to be the same size (except for the last part). The limit to the total number of parts is 1,000. If your number of lines is more than 1,000 than you will need to buffer, so go back to method #1 or add buffering to reduce the number of parts to 1,000.

Unless you are a really motivated developer, realize that method #1 is going to be far easier to implement and test. Methods #2 and #3 will require you to understand how S3 works at a very low level using HTTP PUT requests.